# Field Extension Equality

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I want to show the following:
Let $E/K$ be a field extension and $1+1 \neq 0$. Let $\alpha , \beta \in K^* $. Show

$K(\sqrt{\alpha}$)= $K(\sqrt{\beta}$)$\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists$ a $\gamma \in K^*$ with $\alpha = \gamma ^2 \beta$

Now I had some ideas but they didn't solve the problem for me. A lot would be easier if I could just assume that the $K$-Basis of $K(\alpha$) ist {1,$\alpha$}. But I don't know if that is the case. I would appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Edit: I am really sorry that I forgot to put on the square.. sorry guys. I also would like to add, that we had no minimal polynomial yet.

Best
KingDingeling

Comment: If $\alpha\in K^\times,$ then $K(\alpha) = K.$ Did you mean that $\alpha,\beta\in E^\times\setminus K^\times$ and to also assume that $[E : K] = 2$?

Comment: I forgot to put on the $\sqrt{\alpha}$ and $\sqrt{\beta}$. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E$ is irrelevant now, so I will ignore it. It may serve a technical purpose  equivalent to assuming that all of the below occurs inside a fixed algebraic closure, so that we may actually write that the field extensions are equal instead of just abstractly isomorphic. We will make this assumption. Let $K,\alpha,\beta$ be as in the revised statement.

$K(\sqrt{\alpha})$ and $K(\sqrt{\beta})$ have degrees at most $2$ over $K,$ as the minimal polynomial $f$ of $\sqrt{\alpha}$ divides $x^2 - \alpha$ (and similarly for $\sqrt{\beta}.$ The degree is $2$ if $\sqrt{\alpha}\not\in K,$ and $1$ if $\sqrt{\alpha}\in K.$

First, suppose that $K(\sqrt{\alpha}) = K(\sqrt{\beta}) = K.$ Then $\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{\sqrt{\beta}}\in K,$ and $\alpha = \left(\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{\sqrt{\beta}}\right)^2\beta,$ as required.

Now, suppose that $K(\sqrt{\alpha}) = K(\sqrt{\beta})$ is a degree $2$ extension of $K.$ In this case, $\sqrt{\alpha}\not\in K,$ so that $\{1,\sqrt{\alpha}\}$ is a $K$-basis of $K(\sqrt{\alpha})$ (similarly for $\beta$). This implies that we may write
$$
\sqrt{\beta} = a + b\sqrt{\alpha}
$$
for some $a,b\in K.$ Squaring both sides, we find
$$
\beta = a^2 + 2ab\sqrt{\alpha} + \alpha.
$$
This implies that $2ab\sqrt{\alpha} = \beta - \alpha - a^2\in K,$ and since we already observed that $\{1,\sqrt{\alpha}\}$ is a basis for $K(\sqrt{\alpha})/K,$ this means that $a$ or $b$ is zero (this is where we use the fact that the characteristic is not $2$).

If $b = 0,$ we have $\sqrt{\beta} = a\in K,$ which contradicts the assumption that $K(\sqrt{\alpha}) = K(\sqrt{\beta})$ is a degree $2$ extension of $K.$ Thus, we must have
$$
\sqrt{\beta} = b\sqrt{\alpha},
$$
and squaring both sides gives the desired result.

Comment: Hi @Stahl. Thank you for taking the time and answering this question. You helped me a lot. May I just ask you one thing: We did not have the minimal polynomial yet. I can follow your rational from the point on where you suppose that $K(\sqrt{\alpha})$ is a degree 2 extension of $K$. I have just these two questions: How do we know or can show that the K-basis is $1,\sqrt{\alpha}$? This might seem as a super stupid question but I would very much appreciate if you could answer it. And second: How do we get the degree 2 of the extension without the minimal polynomial? Thank you again for helping!

Comment: We know that $\sqrt{\alpha}$ is a root of $x^2 - \alpha,$ so the minimal polynomial $f$ is degree either $2$ or $1$ (it must divide $x^2 - \alpha$). Since $K(\sqrt{\alpha})\cong K[x]/(f),$ we have that $[K(\sqrt{\alpha}):K] = \deg f.$ Moreover, if the extension is degree two, we *must* have $\sqrt{\alpha}\not\in K.$ Thus, we start with $\{1\}$ which cannot be a basis because it only has one element, and extend it to $\{1,\sqrt{\alpha}\}.$ If $1$ and $\sqrt{\alpha}$ were linearly dependent, we would find $\sqrt{\alpha}\in K.$ Thus, we have a two-element linearly independent set - it is a basis.

Comment: Hey Stahl, thank you again. Unfortunately we did not had minimum polynomials yet, is there any other way to show your argumentation? And just a last question: Could you please explain why $a$ or $b$ is zero?

Comment: Oh, I thought when you said you had no minimal polynomial, you just didn't know what it was in this case, not that you had not covered it in your class. In any case, you know that elements of $K(\sqrt{\alpha})$ are of the form $a_0 + a_1\sqrt{\alpha} + \dots + a_n\sqrt{\alpha}^n,$ where the $a_i\in K.$ You can always assume that $n < 1,$ as  $\sqrt{\alpha}^2 = \alpha\in K.$ If you write this out rigorously, this will show that $\{1,\sqrt{\alpha}\}$ is a basis in the case when $\sqrt{\alpha}\not\in K.$

Comment: Either $a$ or $b$ is zero because $2ab\sqrt{\alpha} = 0,$ and $2$ and $\sqrt{\alpha}$ are both nonzero. $2\neq 0$ because the characteristic is not $2,$ and $\sqrt{\alpha}\neq 0$ because $\alpha\in K^\times$ (if $\sqrt{\alpha} = 0,$ then $\alpha = \sqrt{\alpha}^2 = 0^2 = 0$). If you have a product of elements equal to $0$ in a field, you know that at least one of the elements must be $0$ (if none of them were $0,$ you could multiply both sides by their inverses and get the contradiction $1 = 0$).

Comment: Can't thank you enough, thanks for taking the time. I will sit down and will show that  $\{ x+\beta y : x,y \in K \}$ is a field. I think that will cover that aspect of the basis, shouldn't be that hard. Wish you happy holidays :)

Comment: Thanks, enjoy your holidays and the last few details of this problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

There appear to be some typos in your post, so if you update your question I think that this answer will no longer be valid.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $E=\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$. Take $\alpha=\pi$ and $\beta=\frac{\pi+1}{\pi-1}$. Note that $2(\beta-1)^{-1}+1=\alpha$, so that $K(\alpha)=K(\beta)$.

However, there cannot be a $\gamma\in K^\times$ such that $\alpha=\gamma^2\beta$ or we would have
$$
\pi=\gamma^2\frac{\pi+1}{\pi-1} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \pi^2-(\gamma^2+1)\pi-\gamma^2=0
$$
which is a contradiction, since $\pi$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I have assumed some of the corrections left as a comment on your post, except that $[E:K]=2$. So if you meant that in addition to the fact that $K$ is not characteristic $2$ this answer obviously fails.

EDIT: In fact, I don't even think that the criterion of $[E:K]=2$ is enough to salvage this question. Consider $K=\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)$ and $E=\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$. This is a degree $2$ extension, and if all other choices are made as above then you still end up with a contradiction (though the final contradiction takes a bit more effort to show that it is a nonzero polynomial).

Comment: Thank you for your help and I am really sorry... I forgot to put on the $\sqrt{\alpha}$ and $\sqrt{\beta}$.

Comment: @KingDingeling You still intend for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be in $K^\times$ and not $E\setminus K$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Both are in $K^{\times}$.

Comment: @KingDingeling Final question then; what is the purpose of $E$ in this question?

Comment: I am not sure as well... I think it's just to tell us that $K$ has a field extension, but I am not sure here.

Comment: @KingDingeling Could you find the error in my edit 2? I just read Stahl's answer and it contradicts my work, but I can't find out who is wrong...

Comment: @IAmTheGuy $\gamma = \frac{\pi}{\pi + 1}\in\Bbb Q(\pi)$

Comment: @Stahl Right, but where in my "proof" that we had a non-zero polynomial in $\pi$ did I go wrong?

Comment: @Stahl I see it. Thanks, and that was a nice answer!

Comment: Thank you both. Helped me to understand this question. I hope you have some nice holidays :)